# filter() not working like I expect when using $(this)

Tags: jquery, html, filter

Can someone explain why this works:

```
$(function(){
    $("ol li a").click(function(){
        $("ol li a").filter(":even").css("color", "orange");
    });
});
```

But this doesn't:

```
$(function(){
    $("ol li a").click(function(){
        $(this).filter(":even").css("color", "orange");
    });
});
```

I thought using $(this) in this context would refer to the jquery object which has my original selector in it.

Comment: Do a console.log of `$(this)` and you'll have your answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `$(this)` is a single element (the target of the event) while `$("ol li a")` constains 0 to N elements matching that sector.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is not collection of the elements that correspond to original selector, it is particular element that received the event. If you have selector that returns single element than `$(this)` and `$(selector)` are interchangeable, but not in your case.

Answer (score 2):

When you click the button, the event will fire off and the `$(this)` is created, however, `$(this)` is ONLY the clicked element, not the entire set of elements, therefore it won't be able to filter since it's only one element.